# SQL Server 2008 Rollup with Alias

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the below query and my row total will show NULL as the title and sum will be accurate. I tried using the grouping with case statement nothing seems to work. My search on this site has not provided a solution that worked. If I use the following solution, I get an error:

> Multi-part identifier could not be bound

```
CASE
   WHEN GROUPING(B.Department) = 1  
      THEN 'Total'
      ELSE [B.Department]
END [B.Department],
```

`Select`

```
B.Department,
SUM(CASE datepart(month, [Created on]) WHEN 1 Then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'January'
SUM(CASE datepart(month, [Created on]) WHEN 2 Then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'February'
SUM(CASE datepart(month, [Created on]) WHEN 3 Then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'March'
.
.
SUM(CASE datepart(year, [Created on]) WHEN 2018 Then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD'

FROM 
    [Table Cases] A
LEFT JOIN 
    [Table Departments] B ON A.Department = B.Dept
GROUP BY 
    B.Department WITH ROLLUP
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is solved by using `COALESECE()` or `ISNULL()` e.g.

```
Select
      COALESECE(B.Department,'Total') as Department
    , SUM(CASE datepart(month, [Created on]) WHEN 1 Then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'January'
    , SUM(CASE datepart(month, [Created on]) WHEN 2 Then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'February'
    , SUM(CASE datepart(month, [Created on]) WHEN 3 Then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'March'
    ...
    , SUM(CASE datepart(year, [Created on]) WHEN 2018 Then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'YTD'
FROM [Table Cases] A
INNER join [Table Departments] B On A.Department = B.Dept
GROUP BY B.Department WITH ROLLUP
```

As you are rolling-up by department, do you really need a left join?